# Showing $1/z$ has no holomorphic antiderivative on $\{z\text{ }:\text{ }1<|z|<2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Been awhile since I did complex, and was going over past quals at my university. Can anyone tell me if my proof that $1/z$ has no holomorphic antiderivative on $\{z\text{ }:\text{ }1<|z|<2\}$ checks out.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Let $\log(z)$ represent the principal branch on $\{z\text{ }:\text{ }1<|z|<2\}\backslash(-2,-1)$. We also limit out range of arguments to $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Suppose $F(z)$ was an antiderivative. We consider what an antiderivative on $(1,2)$. Well, an antiderivative of $1/x$ on that region is $\log(x)$, so on $(1,2)$ we have $F(x)=\log(x)+C$. Then by the uniqueness principle it follows that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $$\log(z)+C=F(z)$$ on $$\{z\text{ }:\text{ }1<|z|<2\}\backslash\{z\text{ }:\text{ }-\pi+\epsilon<\arg(z)<\pi-\epsilon\}$$
But then
$$\lim_{z\to1.5}F(z)$$
doesn't exist, for if it did, then
$$\lim_{z\to1.5}\log(z)+C$$
would exist, and it does not. So $F(z)$ fails to be continuous on $\{z\text{ }:\text{ }1<|z|<2\}$ contradicting the assumption that it was holomorphic on said domain.$\blacksquare $

Comment: An  alternative quick answer: Let $C$ be the  circle of radius $1.5$ arond the origin. The integral of any derivative over a closed contour is always $0$ but the integral of $\frac 1 z$ over $C$ is $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant the limit as $z\to-1.5$, not $z\to 1.5$, since the principal branch of the logarithm is continuous on the positive real axis, so that limit would exist. Other than that, your proof is correct, though not elegant. For instance, why consider the domain with an $\varepsilon$-tube cut out? You can directly apply the uniqueness principle to the domain with just the negative real axis removed.

An entirely different, but more elementary approach, would be to show that integrals of $\frac{1}{z}$ are path dependent by calculating

$$\oint_{\vert z\vert=1.5}\frac{1}{z}\mathrm dz\neq0.$$